# C#.NET : Alert Message

Tags: c#

I am creating windows application where at time of sale if item stock is less than 10 (for example) in database then it should so message of low stock alert and it will continue until stock in not updated.

I am not sure whether trigger will be helpful to get this think work around or not. Also, I don't have much understanding of trigger.

Can anyone help me to get it work?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Presumably you are able to lookup items in the database to display them in the application already, so is it that hard to look up the quantity of that item and check < 10, and pop up a message?  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: By message, do you want an email sent out?

Comment: Can you post some code?  What have you tried?

Comment: A database trigger? An event trigger? Please include more detail.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the available quantity in your Database and decide what to do

```
int limit=10;
var availableQuantity=yourRepositary.GetAvailableQuantity();
if(availableQuantity<limit)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Not enough !");
}
else
{ 
   //continue the transaction
}
```

Assuming `GetAvailableQuantity` is a method in your data access layer which gives you the available quantity from the database.

Comment: I am not sure whether to use trigger or not but my design is when you make a sale for any item and if item stock is less than 10 then it should show up alert message box.

Comment: That's what Shyju is showing you here... using a trigger would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not not have triggers.  Are you talking about SQL triggers?  If so then you are assuming they do something they don't.  Triggers in SQL happen on events (like table updates or inserts).

If you are talking about C# events then they might be useful.  This depends on the design of your program and how and when it access the database.